# Is a Sorcerer's Flexible Casting visible?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer

Is there any RAW regarding what it looks like when a sorcerer is burning a spell slot into sorcery points? Is there any way to detect it? I'm thinking about a sorcerer in a social situation who uses subtle spell a lot to cast sneakily, and runs out of sorcery points and needs to make more while still being observed. Can they create more spell points without alerting the observers to the fact that they're doing something magical?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No lore exists either way on this

There's no description of what this looks like or whether or not it is perceptible.  Generally, I find it better to err (both in AL games and in home ones) on the side that things which have no explicitly perceptible component require no perceptible activity-- doing otherwise seems to unnecessarily penalize clever play.  Obviously there's always a judgment call involved at a certain point, but for something like Flexible Casting which has, effectively, no in-fiction description of any sort anywhere, that call can be pretty simple.